# Quick question about the L200 circuit limit

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, current-limiting, linear-regulator

I need some help on how to calculate the output current.. Datasheet:

http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Circuits/Power/l200.pdf

I want to use the (Figure 2. Programmable Current Regulator.) But i don't understand the Io = v5 - 2/R

Is 5 - 2 = PIN 5 minus PIN 2 or something else? Could anyone give me an example? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the term given is the voltage at pin 5 minus the voltage at pin 2 (the datasheet's typesetting does not make this clear). The L200 is measuring the voltage drop across resistor R in Figure 2 to determine the current limit set by the internal comparator. Given in the datasheet is \$V_{5-2}\$ is a typical value with a temperature dependence given in Figure 18.

The explanation of current limiting given in the [ST Designer's Guide](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/10/b7/90/4a/dc/9d/4d/bb/CD00003773.pdf/files/CD00003773.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003773.pdf) on pages 3 and 4 is much more straightforward, using \$V_{sc}\$: the [short-circuit] current limit starts when the L200 sees about 450mV between pins 5 and 2. This avoids the error in typesetting later repeated in Figure 5 of the guide.